# Sending private messages to discord

Tags: python, discord

How to send a private message using a token without using a server bot. I looked through the POST request, but there is a link sent to the ID of the dialog with the user, how do I send a personal message via python by the user ID. For example, I have several user IDs to whom I want to send a message, how do I do this using python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to get the chat ID using the code::

```
userid = 9999999
USER_TOKEN = 'abcdf'
payload = {
    "content": f"Text message."
}
u = 'https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me/channels'
d = {
    "recipients": [f"{userid}"]
}
header = {
    "authorization": USER_TOKEN
}
r = requests.post(url=u, json=d, headers=header) 
jss = json.loads(r.text)
```

And now we are already sending a request to send a message:

```
url = f'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{jss["id"]}/messages' 
r = requests.post(url,data=payload,headers=header)
```

The message has been sent.)